# What would be the best way of getting contents out of parenthesis: (hello)?

Tags: php, regex

I have the following:

(hello)
(hello123)
(hello123$pecialChars&#@)

I need a way to get the contents between the parenthesis each time. What would be a good way of doing that?

Comment: What have you tried? :) Remember that `(` and `)` are special in a regular expression and thus need to be protected.

Comment: I tried this -- >  $items = preg_match_all('#\d+#', $string, $matches); foreach ($matches as $items) { echo $items } but that regex is to extract integers only. My regex sucks so I'm stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well since there aren't spaces in each ( ), the following pattern should work `\(([^ ]+)\)/` (match one or more of anything that isn't a space and is between parenthesis, which are escaped to be literal characters):

```
$data = "(hello) (hello123) (hello123$pecialChars&#@)";
preg_match_all('/\(([^ ]+)\)/', $data, $arr, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

// print_r($arr) gives:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => (hello)
            [1] => (hello123)
            [2] => (hello123$pecialChars&#@)
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => hello
            [1] => hello123
            [2] => hello123$pecialChars&#@
        )

)
```

**Edit:** As mentioned, the pattern `\(([^)]+)\)`, or `match an open parenthesis followed by one or more characters that are not a close parenthesis and are followed by a close parenthesis`,  might be better (depending on if you might have a closing parenthesis in your data or if you might have spaces).

Comment: @pst I like it! Looks nicer, makes more sense, doesn't limit it to non-spaces, and is exactly what he wants.